# Magento: Discount each items differently inside cart

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, shopping-cart-price-rules

The requirements are to have a **discount code** that if the items are already on discount, then discount extra x%, if the items are not on discount, then discount y%. I need to handle the case that both type of these above items appear in the same cart? Is there a existing solutions, or if I need to implement myself, where would I start. Thank you

Comment: Cart or Catalog Pricing Rules don't solve this?

Comment: @B00MER: No it does not. Shopping cart can create coupon rule, that apply to the entire cart, but not individual items different base on condition

Comment: how you can seperate the discount and non discount items ? have you applied any shopping cart price rule for specific items.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 cart rules

1 - if special price <> 0 give x% discount

2 - if special price empty/null/0 give y%

And add General filter to Both for the same product scope (category or other)

This is the closest you can get i think with The default

Comment: if I want to have a discount code to trigger the discount, then I can only create 1 cart rule. Right?